# Erro ao atribuir valor de variável para vetor em C

Tags: c

Estou criando um cadastro de usuários utilizando `struct`. Nele, há o campo CPF. Como é um campo muito grande para guardar em formato de números, decidi salvar como string, assim como em banco de dados onde cpf é salvo com `varchar`.

Eu faço uma validação para não permitir cadastrar 2 cpfs iguais. Para isso, primeiro eu salvo o valor numa váriavel auxiliar e passando na validação eu salvo no vetor. O problema é quando eu passo o valor da variável para o vetor.

Erro na linha onde passo o valor da variável para o vetor: `vet[i].cpf = cpfAux;`

> [Error] assignment to expression with array type

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct colaborador{
    char nome[50];
    char cpf[18];
    char nascimento[11];
    float salario;
};

struct colaborador vet[2];
int i, j;
char nomePesquisa[30];
char cpfAux[18];
int contPesquisa = 0;
bool rep = false;

int cadastra(){


    for(i=0; i<2; i++){ 
        printf("Insira o nome:");
        gets(vet[i].nome);

        printf("Insira o cpf:");
        gets(cpfAux);


            for(j=0; j<2; j++){
                while(strcmp(cpfAux,vet[j].cpf) == 0) {
                    rep = true;
                    printf("ERRO, CPFS IGUAIS!\n\n");

                    printf("Insira o cpf novamente:");
                    gets(cpfAux);                   
                } 

                rep = false;
            }       

            if(rep == false){
                vet[i].cpf = cpfAux;
            }           



        printf("Insira o nascimento:");
        gets(vet[i].nascimento);


        printf("Insira o salario:");
        scanf("%f", &vet[i].salario);               
        fflush(stdin);
    }

}

int pesquisa(){

    printf("Insira um colaborador a ser pesquisado:");
    scanf("%s", &nomePesquisa);

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){     
        if(strcmp(nomePesquisa,vet[i].nome) == 0){
            printf("Nome: %s\n", vet[i].nome);
            printf("CPF: %s\n", vet[i].cpf);
            printf("Nascimento: %s\n", vet[i].nascimento);
            printf("Salario: %2.f\n", vet[i].salario);
            exit(0);
        } else {
            contPesquisa++;
        }
    }

    if(contPesquisa > 0){
        printf("Colaborador nao encontrado.");
    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cadastra(); 
    pesquisa(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Eu testei o código utilizando `int` para o cpf e funcionou. O problema é quando coloco 10-12-15 digitos. Tentei utilizar o tipo `double`, mas quando o primeiro caractere é zero-0, ele não armazena.

Como posso solucionar isso?
Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em `C`, não é possivel copiar o conteúdo de *buffers* contendo *strings* terminadas em `\0` (`array types`) utilizando o operador de atribuição `=`.

O *header* padrão `string.h` fornece uma interface completa para manipulação de strings.

Essa interface possui uma função chamada `strcpy()`, capaz de copiar o conteudo de um *buffer* para outro.

Para resolver seu problema, em primeiro lugar, você deve incluir o header `string.h` no seu programa:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Depois, substitua a linha na qual o erro ocorre por:

```
strcpy( vet[i].cpf, cpfAux );
```

Comment: Não conhecia o `string.h`, muito interessante! Irei ler a respeito para aprender ainda mais. O código rodoou! Muito obrigado Lacobus.

Answer (score 2):

Ao invés de:

```
vet[i].cpf = cpfAux;
```

Você deve utilizar:

```
strcpy(vet[i].cpf, cpfAux);
```

Esse método copia o valor de `cpfAux` e o atribui à `vet[i].cpf`.